# R: Get value in between two patterns

Tags: regex, r

I have a string representing a command line where a binary file and a series of arguments are given.

```
string = "./bin -m A 4 -n 12 --LongName1 12 --LongName2 45 -t Hello -l 0.002 "
```

I'd like to extract the numerical value that is associated to `--LongName1`. How can I do that? Note that `--LongName2` does not necessarily follow `LongName1`. Anything could follow `LongName1` including the end of the string.

I found a solution and it seems to work fine but it is really ugly:

```
re = regexpr("LongName1", string)
start = attr(re, "match.length") + re[1] + 1
nbdigits = which(is.na(sapply(strsplit(substr(string, start, nchar(string)), ""), as.numeric)))[1] - 1
as.numeric(substr(string, start, start + nbdigits - 1))
# 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex with look-behind:

```
string = "./bin -m A 4 -n 12 --LongName1 12 --LongName2 45 -t Hello -l 0.002 "
pattern <- "(?<=--LongName1 )\\d*"
m <- regexpr(pattern, string, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(string, m)
#[1] "12"
```

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. I have no idea how this pattern works but I'll investigate the question.

Comment: Well `\d*` matches 1 or more digits. Look-behind is explained in every basic regex tutorial (in fact I usually search for one since I don't need regex often enough to remember the syntax).